# Adding JDBC jar so Spring Framework can find it

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, spring-jdbc

I am new to Java, Spring, and Eclipse.  I am working on a simple Spring program that is using Spring Framework JDBC to connect to Microsoft SQL Server 2012.  With the correct configuration I have succeeded in using the traditional JDBC to talk to the database.  The problem I am running into is the application is not able to find the Microsoft JDBC driver.  I am assuming it is simply a matter of referencing the JAR file differently.  Here is what I currently have for my classpath file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server/sqljdbc_4.0/enu/sqljdbc4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

And here is the app-context.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=ProSpringCh8"/>
        <property name="username" value="****"/>
        <property name="password" value="****"/>
    </bean>

    <context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="contactDao" class="com.accumed.DatabaseTest.dao.jdbc.xml.JdbcContactDao">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref local="dataSource"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

---

I am running it from within Eclipse's debugger.  The errors I am getting are:

```
09:28:19,711 DEBUG g.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate: 635 - Executing prepared SQL query
09:28:19,726 DEBUG g.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate: 570 - Executing prepared SQL statement [select first_name from contact where id = ?]
09:28:19,774 DEBUG ramework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils: 110 - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Driver'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:573)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:637)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:666)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:674)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:729)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:745)
    at com.accumed.DatabaseTest.dao.jdbc.xml.JdbcContactDao.findFirstNameById(JdbcContactDao.java:55)
    at com.accumed.DatabaseTest.JdbcContactDaoSample.main(JdbcContactDaoSample.java:21)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Driver'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1429)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1420)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Jars are not "configured" in any Spring file. That classpath file is from Eclipse I think but it might be useless outside of Eclipse. How are you calling your application and what error do you get?

Comment: I am calling it from within Eclipse, using the debug feature.  I added the stack trace above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL Server JDBC driver class is `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`, not `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: Thank you!  That was it!  As I said, I am new to Java/Spring/Eclipse.  What throw me off was that in an earlier example, they used this line to get at the driver: Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Driver").  What exactly is that line really doing?  Is Driver some type of static thing that all JDBC implementations have to allow 3rd party code to find the correct class, in this case SQLServerDriver?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can explain it correctly but I'll give it a try:

Comment: `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` is the concrete implementation of the interface `java.sql.Driver` (part of JDBC API). So with the line `Class.forName(...)` you are telling the JVM 'load me this class in the classpath'. When a class is loaded into the classpath, its static blocks are called. The driver implementation must have a static block where it is instantiated and registered in the DriverManager via its static method `DriverManager.registerDriver(driverInstace)`.